# ggplot2 - How can I have two colour schemes when using facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, visualization, facet-wrap

My current plot looks like this:
[image]
But I need the bar colours to change depending on the facet_wrap group they belong to. Put simply, the bars in the 'Colour' group need to show in different shades of colour while the 'Grey' group need to show in different shades of grey. Desired output:
[image]
I understand this will probably double up the items in the legend, and this is fine. I also don't mind if legend items need to be more descriptive (e.g. R.Group.Colour, R.Group.Grey, etc.). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(group = c("R.Group", "R.Group", "R.Group", "R.Group", 
"R.Group", "R.Group", "F.Group", "F.Group", "F.Group", "F.Group", 
"F.Group", "F.Group", "G.Group", "G.Group", "G.Group", "G.Group", 
"G.Group", "G.Group"), mode = c("Grey", "Grey", "Grey", "Colour", 
"Colour", "Colour", "Grey", "Grey", "Grey", "Colour", "Colour", 
"Colour", "Grey", "Grey", "Grey", "Colour", "Colour", "Colour"
), stim = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Words", "Drawings", 
"Photographs"), class = "factor"), emmean = c(0.100851416515973, 
0.108649789029536, 0.0664556962025316, 0.0411392405063291, 0.0574894514767932, 
0.0274261603375527, 0.378405666063894, 0.23372513562387, 0.139240506329114, 
0.185126582278481, 0.209915611814346, 0.0611814345991561, 0.185299879445449, 
0.100663050030139, 0.110759493670886, 0.147151898734177, 0.0743670886075949, 
0.0569620253164557), ymin = c(0.0807866262301694, 0.0848024457881558, 
0.0468323222930633, 0.0269666440471827, 0.0402160043121709, 0.015560956877645, 
0.344334779798359, 0.202260415849806, 0.11272781055522, 0.155246316858577, 
0.178339882849687, 0.0428311209142308, 0.159640657907614, 0.0791229394712789, 
0.0867398048483564, 0.119923200384746, 0.0551207397946581, 0.0390178805506117
), ymax = c(0.120916206801778, 0.132497132270916, 0.0860790701119999, 
0.0553118369654756, 0.0747628986414156, 0.0392913637974605, 0.412476552329429, 
0.265189855397934, 0.165753202103008, 0.215006847698385, 0.241491340779005, 
0.0795317482840815, 0.210959100983284, 0.122203160588998, 0.134779182493416, 
0.174380597083609, 0.0936134374205317, 0.0749061700822997)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

ggplot:

```
    df.plot <-
        ggplot(df, aes(x = stim, y = emmean, fill = group)) +
        scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("R.Group" = "#202124", "F.Group" = "#808083","G.Group" = "#C0C0C0")) + 
        geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), width=0.2, size=0.3, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
        facet_wrap(~mode, strip.position = "bottom") +
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.5)) +
        theme_classic() +
        theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
              axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9),
              axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9),
              strip.placement = "outside",
              strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour = "black"),
              strip.text = element_text(size = 9),
              plot.margin = margin(t = 1, r = 1, b = 0, l = 1, "lines"))
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at package ggnewscale? It allows multiple color scales but I'm not sure about if it works with facets like this.

Comment: You could have R.Colour.Group and R.BW.Group all in the one scale. You'd need to manipulate the data before plotting to do that (dplyr::mutate would sort it).  OR you could create as two plots and merge them together with cowplot ggarrange etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply combine the `group` and `mode` columns into a new column to use for `fill` in `aes()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- df %>% mutate(Group = paste(group, mode, sep = "."))

scale_fill_palette <- c(
    "R.Group.Grey"   = "#202124",
    "F.Group.Grey"   = "#808083",
    "G.Group.Grey"   = "#C0C0C0",
    "R.Group.Colour" = "#e69f00",
    "F.Group.Colour" = "#56b4e9",
    "G.Group.Colour" = "#009e73"
)
df.plot <-
    ggplot(df, aes(x = stim, y = emmean, fill = Group)) +
    scale_fill_manual("legend", values = scale_fill_palette) + 
    geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
    geom_errorbar(
        aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
        width = 0.2, size = 0.3,
        position = position_dodge(0.9)
    ) +
    facet_wrap(~mode, strip.position = "bottom") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.5)) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_rect(
            fill = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour = "black"
        ),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 9),
        plot.margin = margin(t = 1, r = 1, b = 0, l = 1, "lines")
    )
```

[image]